# Split two columns simultaneously in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split, tidyr

I would like to go from this:

```
    data <- data.frame(sequence = "abc", position = "1;2", probability = "0;1")
        
    > data
          sequence position probability
        1      abc      1;2         0;1
```

to this:

```
result <- data.frame(sequence = "abc", position = c(1,2), probability = c(0,1))

    > result
      sequence position probability
    1      abc        1           0
    2      abc        2           1
```

Do you have an idea of how I could achieve this? I have been playing around with `separate` and `pivot_longer` but I feel like there must be a smarter way to achieve the end result.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `separate_rows`.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(sequence = "abc", 
                      position = "1;2", 
                      probability = "0;1")


data %>% 
  separate_rows(c(position, probability), sep = ";")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   sequence position probability
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>      
#> 1 abc      1        0          
#> 2 abc      2        1
```

Created on 2021-04-22 by the reprex package (v2.0.0)

Comment: That solved my problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, ";"))), sequence]
```

which gives

```
   sequence position probability
1:      abc        1           0
2:      abc        2           1
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `cSplit`

```
library(data.table)
cSplit(data, c('position', 'probability'), sep=";", "long")
#   sequence position probability
#1:      abc        1           0
#2:      abc        2           1
```